# How to improve regexp based replace on cells to operate per line instead of needing to loop through each cell?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

If you need to clean content in the "cells" of a tsv (tab separated values) file, where the cleaning operation needs include removing certain characters at the beginning and end of each column per line as well as in some cases characters in the middle of the content, then this approach works (ubuntu/linux):

(the example below is using `awk` but any tool/utility like `sed`,`tr`, core `bash` functionality that can be run from a bash script is the goal)

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS="\t"} \
{for (i=1; i <= NF ; i++) \
gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|[[:cntrl:]]+|(\\|\/)+$/, "", $i) \
gsub(/(\+$|^\+)/, "", $i) \
# and so on (could add more replacement conditions here)
;print $0 }' ${file} > ${file}.cleaned
```

However when these files are very large, it can take a long time to process because it is breaking each line up into the cells and processing each cell. I want to see if the processing time for the same cleanup operations can be improved.

Can this be rewritten so that instead of breaking up the columns per line and doing the replacement per cell, a regular expression could be constructed to do the same cleanup operations (more could be added later to the above example) on all columns in between the column separator (tabs) for the entire line all at once?

The approach should consider the files to be cleaned have a dynamic/varying number of columns for the file contents (i.e. its not just 2 or 3 columns, could be 10 or more) so building a fixed regular expression based on a known number of columns isn't an option. However, the script could build the regular expression dynamically based on first determining how many columns there are and then execute the result. I am curious though if a statically constructed regular expression could be built to do this for the entire line where it knows how to remove certain characters between the content and the tabs for each cell without removing the tabs.

**Update** to clarify, in the above example there are some characters that need to be removed anywhere in the cell content (defined as in between the tabs) and others that need to be removed at beginning or end of content (i.e. [[:space:]]) and some of the characters to replace would include a tab (i.e. [[:cntrl:]] and [::space:]]). This update is to clear up any confusion I may have suggested that all cases for removal are just at beginning or end of cell content.

Comment: This isn't a "bash regexp" -- it's purely awk. awk is not part of bash; it's a completely separate language, and you can use it without having bash installed at all. (bash *does* have its own regex facilities, but you aren't using them here -- and as the bash built-in facilities are slower than awk's when handling long enough inputs to overcome startup overhead, I wouldn't suggest swapping them out).

Comment: I understand that but it doesn't change the problem definition or goal really - the example above is just an `awk` example that runs in bash script. The desired answer/goal is that it still be run from a bash script but it can use whatever appropriate tools necessary to execute a regular expression to clean content of a file (per line or all at once). It could be `tr`, `awk`, or core `bash` or other.

Comment: So, the general "work on the whole line" answer is to operate only on `$0`, rather than iterating over `$i` values from 1 onward. I suppose a [mcve] letting people test their answers here would involve code that generates a stream of representative input long enough to enable benchmarking.

Comment: ... or to use `sed`, which doesn't do field splitting in the first place.

Comment: Right, that's the reason for the post. I would like to understand how to use `awk` using `$0` or `sed` or other tools but would need to understand how to construct the regular expression correctly first to do that. Ultimately this is a question about how to construct the regexp (knowing that the syntax may vary depending on the tool)

Comment: ...so you want to modify your regexps... to not match tabs anywhere, so the replacements stay inside of individual fields? It's not obvious to me that that will actually be faster.

Comment: If the replacement field is the empty string in every case, one thing I *would* consider is having just one `gsub()` call per field with a composite regex. GNU Awk uses Thompson NFA-style regexes, so they're [quite speedy](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) themselves (much faster than the PCRE-inspired regex libraries with all the backtracking-based features that have been all the rage for the last decades).

Answer (score 1):

Sed has a rather more cryptic syntax than does Awk, but for simple substitutions where field-splitting is not required, it's not *that* cryptic.  Certainly the regex syntax itself is the hardest part about it, and that does not change appreciably among the various regex-based tools.  For example,

```
sed \
  -e 's,^[ \r\v\f]\+\|\([ \r\v\f]\+\|[\\/]+\)$,,g' \
  -e 's,\([ \r\v\f]*\|[\\/]*\)\t[ \r\v\f]*,\t,g' \
  -e 's,[\x00-\x08\x0a-\x1f\x7f]\+,,g' \
  -e 's,^\+|\+$,,g' \
  -e 's,+\?\t+\?,\t,g' \
  ${file} > ${file}.cleaned
```

That performs the same transformation that your Awk script does (for reals now, I think).  There are some catches there, however, large among them:

- because you get no field splitting, you have to match not only at the beginning and end of each input, but also around the field delimiters;
- yet you need to watch out for matching the field delimiter elsewhere (the first version of this answer did not do an adequate job of that, because the tab is included in both `[[:space:]]` and `[[:cntrl:]]`);
- you will want to perform at least some of your substitutions with the `g` (global) flag to replace *all* matches instead of just the first.  In Awk, that's the difference between `gsub` and `sub`.  In Sed and several other languages it's the difference between supplying the '`g`' flag or not.

You could of course package up exactly the same thing with Awk, Perl, *etc*. without much substantive change.  Whether any variation is a *bona fide* improvement over your original per-field Awk approach is a matter of style preference and performance testing.

Comment: `[[:space:]]` charset includes `tabs` as well.  It may not work as intended, if the file is tab delimited!

Comment: In the comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257724/how-to-improve-regexp-based-replace-on-cells-to-operate-per-line-instead-of-need#comment87533844_50257724, the OP indicates that they consider building a regex *with equivalent behavior to the field-based behavior when operating on a full line* (thus, one where no element will match a tab; and where `^` and `$` can be matched immediately after or before a tab) a core element of the question at hand.

Comment: Interesting... I updated my post to clarify that I need to address both cases where characters to remove are at beginning, end or anywhere in the cell content (depending on the character to remove). I will make an attempt to try setting this `sed` example today and see how far I get.

Comment: You are quite right, @karakfa, as I realized after stepping away from the computer.  I have fixed that deficiency in the regexen.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, the example command in my original offering was flawed in several ways, though I think the prose nevertheless addressed the concern you raise.  I've substantially revised the command and prose.

Comment: Haven't done any testing yet but saw your updates and wanted to comment before my next meeting - really would prefer to continue to use class control characters for [[:space:]] because there are many whitespace & non printable characters across different characters sets that it includes - you can't assume it is limited to the `\r\v\f` etc. - there are more beyond ASCII . Does sed's regexp allow for character class subtraction so we can do [[:space:]] - \t ? Also the goal for any change is performance so style is a wash really. I will test and report back.

Comment: @Streamline, POSIX Sed and Awk both rely on POSIX regular expressions, and this regex language does not have a character class subtraction or intersection mechanism (few do).  There may be implementations that provide such a thing as an extension, but I am not specifically aware of any.  Do note, however, that although the characters represented by `[[:space:]]` in a POSIX regex do depend on the locale, in the default (C) locale they are exactly `[ \t\r\n\v\f]`.

Comment: I've finally gotten some time to start testing. As part of another related cleaning task, I've needed to set the locale to en_US.UTF-8 which makes the `-e 's,[\x00-\x08\x0a-\x1f\x7f]\+,,g'` fail with a collation error. I think the modified version that will work with that locale setting is `-e 's,[\x00\x01-\x08\x0a-\x1f\x7f]\+,,g'` per some initial but not yet complete testing.